# minimax procedure on unbalanced tree

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I think I understand it, but all the examples I have found show a balanced tree. If I have an unbalanced tree I still do it the same way right? Am I correct in saying the answer here is 4 from the h node?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The procedure is the same for unbalanced trees. Each row in the tree alternates between Max-player choosing the maximum of its children and the Min-player choosing the minimum of its children.

Node *b* is a Min-player node and will get the value 3 as it is the minimum of *d* (value 5) and *e* (value 3). Node *i* is a Min-player node and will get the value 0 since it is the minimum of *m* (value 0) and *n* (value 7). Node *f* is a Max-player node and will get the value 5 since it is the maximum of *i* (value 0) and *j* (value 5). Node *g* is a Max-player node and will get the value 8 since it is the maximum of *k* (value 8) and *l* (value 7). Node *c* is a min-player node and will get the value of 4 since it is the minimum of *f* (value 5), *g* (value 8) and *h* (value 4). Finally, node *a* is a Max-player node and will get the value 4 since it is the maximum of *b* (value 3) and *c* (value 4).

The image below shows the resulting minimax tree. Best values in each node are marked in red labels.

[Minimax tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHMc5.png)